# How to create two tables linked with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

This is my problem:
I´m working in a database named `David`, there I´m trying to create two tables:`colores`and`productos` which will be linked by a foreign key where the father table will be `colores`and the son table will be `productos`, but when I click continue this message appears:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

someone could help me?

This is the code that I wrote:

```
create table `color`(
    id_color int(3)not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(30)not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_color)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


create table`producto`(
    id_producto int(3)NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(30)not null,
    id_color int(3)not null,
    precio decimal(10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_producto),
    INDEX(id_color),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_color)
    REFERENCES`color`(id_color) on UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE= INNODB;
```

This is the code that I wrote.
[image]

This is the error that appears.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem technically is just the missing space after the word `references` but the whole thing needs a few more spaces.

```
create table `color`(
    id_color int(3) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_color)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

create table`producto`(
    id_producto int(3) NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    id_color int(3) not null,
    precio decimal(10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_producto),
    INDEX(id_color),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_color)
    REFERENCES `color`(id_color) on UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE= INNODB;
```

Also, `NOT NULL` is not necessary on PK columns. Just saying. It becomes automatic and redundant.